# what does if(a) exactly check in javascript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

1. What does if(a) exactly check in javascript? Can it check undefined? Can it check null? Can it check an empty string?
2. When do we need to use typeof a == 'undefined' or it could be covered by if(a)?

Comment: Read: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if` evaluates `a` in a boolean context and uses the result to determine which code branch to execute. `undefined`, `null` and the empty string all evaluate to `false` in a boolean context.

`typeof a === "undefined"` is useful to check if the name `a` is defined (e.g. if a variable with that name exists in the current scope). Without this construct, accessing `a` directly would throw an exception if it is not defined.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from the [ECMAscript language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), the if-Statement works as the following:

> #### 12.5 The if Statement
>
> The production IfStatement : if ( Expression ) Statement is evaluated as follows:
>
> > 1. Let **exprRef** be the result of evaluating Expression.
> > 2. If **ToBoolean(GetValue(exprRef))** is false, return (normal, empty, empty).
> > 3. Return the result of evaluating Statement.

Means, in such cases, it would try a `toBoolean` conversion which acts like this:

> #### Table 11 - ToBoolean Conversions
>
> Undefined: **false**
>   Null: **false**
>   Boolean: The result equals the input argument (no conversion).
>   Number: The result is **false** if the argument is **+0**, **-0**, or **NaN**; otherwise the result is **true**.
>   String: The result is **false** if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); 
>   otherwise the result is **true**.
>   Object: **true**

Answer (score 1):

It checks for a value not being false-ish, i. e. `false`, `0`, `undefined` and `null` or an empty string. `typeof a == 'undefined'` is useful when you are curious if a value is undefined or not, since `if (a)` can't make the distinction between the false-ish values.

Comment: I did not downvote but `if()` is supposed to check truthy values. A falsy means the if block won't execute.

Comment: *An empty string is not considered false-ish.* Nope, empty strings are falsish. *if (a) can't make the distinction between the false-ish values.* If it cannot make this distinction, how is the right branch taken?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Right, damn, the empty string is false.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi But branching won't do anything different when fed `0`, `false`, `null`, `undefined` or `""`.

Comment: @H2CO3, true, but that is not actually related to the use of `typeof a === 'undefined'`, as your answer seems to suggest.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi What's related then? If I understand correctly, OP wants to know why to use `typeof a == 'undefined'` instead of `if (!a)`.

Comment: @H2CO3, it seems you're confusing `if (typeof a === "undefined")` and `if (a === undefined)`. The first construct will take the `then` branch if the name `a` doesn't exist, the second will throw an exception. Both will work if the name `a` exists and contains `undefined`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No, I'm not confusing these. The question is unclear and you're twisting my words.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional statement will only check for 'true' or 'false'.
in case of undefined the condition is not satisfied and control does not go into the loop.

typeof returns the type of operand. for details you may want to see [this link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/determinevar2.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

following values are considered as false in javascript conditions: false, null, undefined,'', 0, NaN

Answer (score 0):

the answer by h2co3 is actually almost correct, you can *not* check for undefined variables in an if without typeof as this will cause a script error.

if you do this:

```
<script>
if (a) alert('hello');
</script>
```

you will get a script error and the if will not be evaluated (the result is the same in the sense that alert is not shown, but that's because the thread execution ended due to the script error.)

if you want to make sure a is defined you need to use the typeof test.